# How to set row_format globally in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Under mysql prompt, I type in the following,

```
mysql> set global innodb_default_row_format = DYNAMIC;
```

But it returns with the error:

> unknown system variable innodb_default_row_format.

What is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: what's your mysql version? Note: The innodb_default_row_format option, introduced in MySQL 5.7.9

Answer (score 5):

What is your server version?

```
mysql> select @@version;
```

[`innodb_default_row_format`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_default_row_format) was introduced in MySQL 5.7.9 and is not available in previous versions.

Comment: Actually, the version of my mysql is 5.5.52. Is there any way to set row_format globally in this version? Thanks.